# C# Generics: there is no way to constrain a type to have a static method?

Tags: c#, generics

Could somebody kindly explain this to me, in **simple** words:

> there is no way to constrain a type to
>   have a static method. You cannot, for
>   example, specify static methods on an
>   interface.

many thanks in advance to you lovely people :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With generics, you can add a constraint that means the generic-type supplied must meet a few conditions, for example:

- `where T : new()` - `T` must have a public parameterless constructor (or be a `struct`)
- `where T : class` - `T` must be a reference-type (`class` / `interface` / `delegate`)
- `where T : struct` - `T` must be a value-type (other than `Nullable<TSomethingElse>`)
- `where T : SomeBaseType` - `T` must be inherited from `SomeBaseType` (or `SomeBaseType` itself)
- `where T : ISomeInterface` - `T` must implement `ISomeInterface`

for example:

```
public void SomeGenericMethod<T>(T data) where T : IEnumerable {
    foreach(var obj in data) {
        ....
    }
}
```

it is `SomeBaseType` and `ISomeInterface` that are interesting here, as they allow you to demand (and use) functions defined on those types - for example, `where T : IList` gives you access to `Add(...)` etc. HOWEVER! simply: there is no such mechanism for things like:

- constructors with parameters
- static methods
- operators / conversions
- arbitrary methods not defined via a base-type or interface

so: you can't demand those, and you can't use them (except via reflection). For some of those `dynamic` can be used, though.

Answer (score 6):

so, basically:

```
public class A{}

public class B{
  public static void Foo() {}
}
```

You can't write a generic constraint for `T` in:

```
public class C<T> {}
```

Such that you restrict to accept only `A` or `B` based on the presence or non-presence of the static method `Foo()`.

Comment: The first part of your answer is just excellent. The second part is just confusing. _Don't explain it if it's not there_.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following not working code:

```
interface IWithStatic
{
    void DoIt(); // non-static
    static void DoItStatic(); // static
}

class C1 : IWithStatic
{
    void DoIt() {} // non-static
    static void DoItStatic(){} // static
}

class C2 : IWithStatic
{
    void DoIt() {} // non-static
    static void DoItStatic(){} // static

}
```

And, in a program :

```
IWithStatic myObj = GetWithAnyMethod(); // Return a C1 or C2 instance

myObj.DoIt(); // working, as the runtime type is used (either C1 or C2);
```

but with the static... how can the compiler interpret this :

```
IWithStatic.DoItStatic(); // Not knowing which type to use
```

Do you see what's the problem now ?

Comment: An interface defines a contract a class must respect. This contract allow consumers of the class to work with variables declared with the interface type, not the actual implementation. The actual implementation is determined at run-time. The consuming code is guaranteed to have the called method available. all of this can work because the run-time have an instance to work on. If you work with statics methods, you do not have a variable to check the type at run-time. The compiler does not have way to determine if its C1.DoItStatic or C2.DoItStatic to call

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have:

```
public interface IInterface {
   static void Method();
}
```

This is because you are not allowed/able to constrain implementing classes to methods being static.

Comment: But this generates the error message `The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item`

Comment: @Lucero - It was probably a little unlear, but my point was that this generates a different message to the one being asked about. The answer also does not addreses the inference of generic constraints in the original question. :-)

Comment: @James Wiseman, fair enough, I'm not saying this is the perfect answer. I just wanted to point out that Fourth correctly stated that static methods on interfaces are not possible, that's all. Sorry for any confusion caused!

Comment: A bit off topic but helpful, +1